# Problem in Google Map API...!

Tags: google-maps

Hi there i'm currently working with google map api

for plotting multiple address with marker

i have written the following code as i understand the api function while study from google api documentation

```
for(var i=0; i<address.length; i++){
geocoder.getLocations(address[i],function(response){    
            if(response){
                place = response.Placemark[0];
                  point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1], place.Point.coordinates[0]);
                map.setCenter(point, 12);
                map.addOverlay(createmarker(point));
            }
});
}
```

createmarker is my function which works properly but the problem is this 
this place random markers with the address comes from address array
sometimes 10, 12, 14, 14, and so on ....

I just want to plot all the address exists in my address array and on the google maps too..

so it must be fixed number of markers onto the map...!

So is there anyone who can help me for this issue..!

Thanks is advanced

Comment: You need to help us with additional information.  What your code is doing right now is trying to plot multiple addresses.  Do all the addresses geocode properly?  What happens when you only use a single address in your array?  Do you realize that the geocoder is doing an asynchronous call, so your points are not going to appear on the map in the order of the array.  Also, you keep recentering the map fro each point, which will be annoying to end users when the map keeps jumping around.

Comment: Actually I just want to plot all the address in my address array to map i have send you my code its just plot the makers dynamically i want to plot all address on the map should i use anything else for geocoding my address or its fine,, When i have enter a single address its working fine so why its make problem with my loop ho will i solve it any idea or code..!

Answer (score 1):

The `createMarker` function should look like this. Please see my example [here](http://tallymobile.com/test5.html), where you can add multiple markers on the map. Complete javascript can be found [here](http://tallymobile.com/beam.js).

```
function createMarker(latlng) {
   var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    marker.MyZoom = zoom; 
    return marker; 
}
```